# Installed MATE Desktop, can't select it in login screen

Tags: 16.04, desktop-environments, mate

So, I just installed the MATE Desktop environment, when I go to the login screen and i click the little ubuntu icon, I only see the Unity selection, any help?

(by the way i love that desktop environment)

Comment: Do you have light-dm-greeter installed?

Comment: Yes, I do. Still can't see the MATE option.

Comment: Which is your default greeter?

Comment: light-dm-greeter is my default, still can't se the MATE option

Comment: I just installed Ubuntu MATE desktop using 'sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop'  and it showed in the greeter menu.

Comment: Please edit your question providing the output of `ls /usr/share/xsessions/
` and `ls ls /usr/share/xgreeters/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you installed MATE DE correctly:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^
```

If session is not shown try to reinstall `mate-session-manager` package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mate-session-manager
```

and then reboot.

Comment: Thank you norbert, now i can see it in the greeter menu!

Comment: Reboot helps making it show up.